# Computing the FT of the pullback of the Heaviside distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I'm very comfortable with the computation for the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function in $\mathbb{R}$, and I'm more or less familiar with pullbacks of distributions (like the delta distribution along the diagonal: $\delta(x-y)$)

Out of sheer curiosity I tried computing the Fourier transform of the distribution $H(x-y)$, however I've been having trouble getting a clean formula in the end.

Obviously if $u(x,y) = H(x-y)$ were this distribution, then
$$\begin{align} \langle\widehat{u},\phi \rangle &:= \langle u, \widehat{\phi} \rangle\\ &= \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} H(\xi-\eta)\widehat{\phi}(\xi,\eta) \,d\xi d\eta \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} H(s)\widehat{\phi}\left( \tfrac{1}{2}(t+s), \tfrac{1}{2}(t-s) \right) dsdt\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\widehat{\phi}\left( \tfrac{1}{2}(t+s), \tfrac{1}{2}(t-s) \right) dsdt\\ &=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left\{ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi(x,y) \, e^{-i\left( \tfrac{1}{2}(t+s)x+\tfrac{1}{2}(t-s)y \right)} dxdy\right\}dsdt \end{align}$$

Here is where I'm getting stuck. I've tried throwing in a cutoff $e^{-\varepsilon s}$ to help with the $ds$ integral, but I'm not exactly sure what to do about the $dt$ integral. I've even tried throwing in a second cutoff, $e^{-\varepsilon |t|}$, but the expressions I get in terms of $x$, $y$, and $\varepsilon$ are quite complicated and I'm not sure how to precisely evaluate the distributional limit as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$:

$$ \begin{align} \widehat{u}(x,y) &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{-8i\varepsilon}{(x-y-2i\varepsilon)((x+y)^2 + 4\varepsilon^2)}\\ &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{(x+y)^2 + 4\varepsilon^2} \left( \frac{16\varepsilon^2}{(x-y)^2 + 4\varepsilon^2} + i \frac{8\varepsilon(y-x)}{(x-y)^2 + 4\varepsilon^2} \right) \\ &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \left( \frac{8\varepsilon}{\left((x+y)^2 + 4\varepsilon^2 \right) \left( (x-y)^2 + 4\varepsilon^2 \right)} \right) \left( 2\varepsilon + i(y-x) \right) \end{align}$$

Any suggestions?

**edit:** Since $H(x)$ has a nice transform, and since pullbacks like $\delta(x-y)$ can be expressed nicely as line integrals in the plane, I feel like there should be some closed formula for this distribution.

I even tried plugging it into Mathematica, but I get something rather odd:
$$ \widehat{u} = 2\pi^2 \delta(x)\delta(x+y)-2\pi i \frac{\delta(x+y)}{x} $$
This is especially troubling to me since Mathematica seems to be multiplying distributions together, which I know is not allowed in most cases. In particular, it looks like Mathematica thinks the imaginary part involves the product the Cauchy principal value and the delta distribution, which I know for sure is not defined.

Comment: I don't know, but [these notes](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf) should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already looked through all of that years ago. The computation in $R^1$ is much more straightforward. This is proving much different from that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to a rotation, you want to compute the Fourier transform of $v(x, y):=H(y)$. This is 
$$
\hat{v}(\xi, \eta)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2} H(y)e^{-ix\xi}e^{-iy\eta}\, dxdy = 2\pi \delta(\xi) \hat{H}(\eta), $$ 
where $\hat{H}$ is the 1-dimensional Fourier transform of $H$.

**REMARK**. In this formula, we multiply the distributions $(\xi, \eta)\mapsto \delta(\xi)$ and $(\xi, \eta)\mapsto \hat{H}(\eta)$. This looks suspicious, because the product of distributions is not well-defined in general. However, [as these lecture notes of Christian Brouder, Nguyen Viet Dang, Frédéric Hélein](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1778) explain, such a product **is** well-defined when the singular sets are transversal, and it is the present case. (I think that §2.1.3 of the notes is all we really need here, and nothing more).

To apply this result to the original function $u(x, y)=H(x-y)$, we observe that 
$$
u(x, y)=v(x+y, x-y), $$
and we recall the following general property of the Fourier transform; for every nonsingular matrix $A$, 
$$
\mathcal F(v(A\cdot))(\xi, \eta) = \frac{1}{\lvert \det A\rvert} \mathcal F(v)\left(A^{-T}\begin{bmatrix} \xi\\\eta\end{bmatrix}\right).$$
In our case, 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}, $$ 
with determinant $-2$, so the end result is 
$$
\pi\delta(\tfrac{\xi+\eta}{2})\hat{H}(\tfrac{\xi-\eta}{2}).$$

Comment: The problem I have, though, is that if you rotate the jump discontinuity to be the upper half-plane, then you'll need to rotate the test function $\phi$ as well. How should I account for such a transformation in a distributional calculation?

Comment: I would just use a general property of the Fourier transform, which is easily proved by a change of variable in the integral and which extends to distributions, for example by a density argument. I added details.

Comment: You don't seem to be satisfied with my answer. Maybe I have a computational mistake? It can well be. I also notice that you mention the product of distributions, which is normally a no-no, and I have one such product in my answer, since $\hat{H}$ is a distribution. However, you **can** multiply distributions if their singular support is transversal. I don't really know the meaning of this in the general case, but I do in the special case of Dirac deltas; for example, $\delta(x)\delta(y)$ makes perfectly sense. Similarly, the product I have in this answer makes sense. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Sorry for the late reply, I was just busy. I appreciate the first equation you pointed out there; I hadn't thought of separating the two exponentials into two transforms like that before. I'm a little shaky though as to how exactly we should define the product of those two distributions? Especially since $\hat{H}(\eta)$ involves the Cauchy principal value distribution as well as another Dirac delta terms.

Comment: I have added a link to some very good notes which explain that such a product of distributions is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. That link is rather interesting. After carefully going through *all* of the details in the argument you've laid out above, the only issue I have is that the plus and minus should be swapped in your end result. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it helped. I fixed the signs in the final formula, thank you for noticing.